# Как получить массив через json

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте, у меня есть такой php файл

```
 <?php
 echo json_encode(array ("1" => "probel"));
 ?>
```

Как я могу получить это через jquery json?

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт непосредственно на странице:

```html
<?php
echo '
<script>
  $(function() {
 var json_array = "'. json_encode(array ("1" => "probel")); .'";
  });
</script>
';

?>
```

Или помещаем массив в атрибут некого элемента и средствами jquery получаем его

```js
$(function() {
  var json_array = $("#json_array").attr("data");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="json_array" data="<?php echo json_encode(array ("1" => "probel")); ?>"></p>
```